# how to do use onclick inside innerhtml

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have craeted a new div and inside the div Idisplay the information about a topic and also a link to read more about the topic, but my onlick funciton is not working it keeps telling that id is not define. How can I pass value thru innerHTML

```
   function displayNews(section, id, title) {
        var section = section;
        var id      = id;
        var title   = title;  

    contentDiv.innerHTML = '<div onclick="displayInfo(id, title);">More info</div>';
}
```

Comment: This is not going to work. In order to `id` and `title` having values, they should be global, which leads to unwanted values when the event fires.

Comment: Should `contentDiv` be `section` ?

Comment: @Taplar Im using section to see if the id is a car, food etc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could make a real element rather than html to optionally do this.

```js
function displayNews(section, id, title) {
  var section = section;
  var id = id;
  var title = title;
  var element = document.createElement('div');
  
  element.onclick = function () {
    displayInfo(id, title);
  };
  
  element.innerHTML = "More info";
  //i don't see contentDiv defined, but this shows the operation
  contentDiv.appendChild(element);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for you help @taplar this works perfect!

Answer (score -1):

You didn't properly concatenate the values.

This is what you meant to do, I guess:

```js
function displayNews(section, id, title) {
  var section = section;
  var id = id;
  var title = title;

  var div = '<div onclick="displayInfo(' + id + ', "' + title + '");">More info</div>';
  
  alert(div);
}

displayNews(1, 2, 3);
```

Comment: Both parameters will be undefined variables.

Comment: This is incorrect. You're setting up variables to be passed to `displayInfo`, which likely don't exist.

Comment: This will be passing the value of the variables, not the variables themselves.

Comment: No, it will not. Try to imagine what the resulting code will be.

Comment: @Phiter: No, the value of the variables will be passed as variable names (or some other possibly invalid code). So if `id` is `"foo"` and `title` is `"bar"`, it'll be `displayInfo(foo, bar)`

Comment: I meant to correct that. I put the quotes around title, but I didn't put it around ID because  it could be a integer.